# Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate $$\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}dx$$
By making the substitution $x=\tan\theta$,  $$\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\exp(-\tan\theta)d\theta$$ So it converges to something less than $\frac \pi 2$. Is there any way to  find the exact value, using only elementary methods?

Comment: You can evaluate the integral in terms of the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Comment: I know but I don't consider that elementary. I also don't know enough about the exponential integral to like using it.

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: Not every integral can be evaluated in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: The indefinite integral isn't elementary , but is it possible to  do one with these limits without involving the exponential integral?

Comment: Nope. Look up the Laplace transform of $\frac1{1+x^2}$ in any convenient table (or evaluate with any software at hand), and report back.

Comment: @J.M: The Laplace transform of this function is in terms of the exponential function. Here is the Laplace transform $$ 1/2\,i \left( {{\rm e}^{is}}{\it Ei} \left( 1,is \right) -{{\rm e}^{-i
s}}{\it Ei} \left( 1,-is \right)  \right)
. $$

Comment: Not quite, @Mhenni. Exponential **integral** maybe...

Comment: @J.M. I did and found stuff involving Ci and Si.

Comment: Ishan, quite right. Those functions are related to $\mathrm{Ei}$ in much the same way $\cos$ and $\sin$ are related to $\exp$; hence @Mhenni's first comment.

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: These are the sine and cosine integrals and they are related to exponential integrals.

Comment: So, what do I do now? Do I delete the question, seeing as they can't be solved using only elementary functions?

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: Why should you delete it? Just leave it.

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: It is a good idea to have a close look at some special functions to be able to handle some of these non elementary integrals.

Comment: One can use Chebyshev polynomials for $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and then the integrals are computable. But then one has to cope with a series that can also have convergence problems.

Comment: Can you elaborate on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_.28II.29_.E2.80.93_Cauchy_distribution) ?

Comment: Taylor expanding the denominator and then integrating term-by-term gives a divergent series: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2n)!.$$ I wonder if this can be converted to a convergent series.

Comment: @arbautjc Referring to the link ,the integral on the big arc doesn't tend to 0 for this case.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in the comments and in Xiaolang's answer, this integral is very unlikely to have a closed-form solution in terms of elementary functions, but it is possible to express it in terms of exponential integrals or, equivalently, sine and cosine integrals. These hardly qualify as "elementary methods", but we can at least eliminate the sine and cosine integrals using their power series expansions.

We start with the representation in terms of the cosine and sine integrals $\operatorname{Ci}$ and $\operatorname{Si}$:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2} &= \operatorname{Ci}(1)\sin(1) - \operatorname{Si}(1)\cos(1)+\frac{\pi \cos(1)}{2},\\\ \\
\operatorname{Ci}(x) &= \gamma + \ln(x) +\int_0^x \frac{\cos(t)-1}{t}dt, \\\ \\
\operatorname{Si}(x) &= \int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt,
\end{align}
where $\gamma=0.577\ldots$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Power series expansions for $\operatorname{Ci}(x)$ and $\operatorname{Si}(x)$ follow directly from their definitions in terms of sines and cosines:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Ci}(x) &= \gamma + \ln(x) + \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j+1}x^{2j+2}}{(2j+2)!(2j+2)},\\\ \\
\operatorname{Si}(x) &= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^jx^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!(2j+1)}.
\end{align}
Substituting $x=1$ into these expressions, applying the power series expansions for $\sin(1)$ and $\cos(1)$ where they multiply $\operatorname{Ci}(1)$ and $\operatorname{Si}(1)$, and doing a somewhat non-negligible amount of arithmetic, we find:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2} = \gamma \sin(1) + \frac{\pi\cos(1)}{2} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{f(j-k)}{j(j!)(k!)}. \tag{$\star$}$$
Here the function $f(j-k)$ is the sequence $0,-1,0,1,\ldots$:
\begin{align}
f(j-k) &= 0\ \ \quad \textrm{if}\quad j-k\equiv 0\ (\operatorname{mod} 4)\\
       &= -1\ \ \ \,\textrm{if}\quad j-k\equiv 1\ (\operatorname{mod} 4)\\
       &= 0\ \ \quad \textrm{if}\quad j-k\equiv 2\ (\operatorname{mod} 4)\\
       &= 1\ \ \quad \textrm{if}\quad j-k\equiv 3\ (\operatorname{mod} 4).\\
\end{align}
Clearly Eq. $(\star)$ converges rapidly, considering the factorial functions in the denominator of the summand. Indeed, including just 25 terms (5 values for each index), we obtain 0.621..., consistent with the result 0.621449... quoted previously.

Comment: PS. In your question you quote $\pi/2$ as an upper bound. Actually, note that we have $1/(x^2+1)\leq 1\ \forall\ x\in\mathbb{R}$, with the equality only at $x=0$. This gives: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{{x^2+1}}dx < 1=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}dx.$$

Comment: Though we didn't get an elementary answer, your post provided some additional insight. Congratulations to the +100.

Comment: @MårtenW Thanks. I found this problem challenging and had fun looking at it. It's a shame that the double sum in $(\star)$ couldn't be identified with any known constants. I'd be interested to hear if someone manages to do better.

Answer (score 2):

there may not be a elementray functions but it isn't a easy thing to prove you can consult The Liouville's therom in complex analysis

but you can get a approximation (WolframAlpha can help you)

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{\tan(\theta)}d\theta= \operatorname{Ci}(1)\sin(1)- \operatorname{Si}(1)\cos(1)+\pi \cos(1)/2 \approx 0.62144962423581335763926$$