# Evaluate series: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\left[ k\ln\left(\frac{k^4+2k^3+k^2}{k^4+2k^3+3k^2+2k+2}\right)+\ln\frac{k^2+2k+1}{k^2+1} \right]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, improper-integrals

The series is
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\left[ k\ln\left(\frac{k^4+2k^3+k^2}{k^4+2k^3+3k^2+2k+2}\right)+\ln\left(\frac{k^2+2k+1}{k^2+1}\right)  \right] $$
You won't believe it: this has a closed form! It's the beautiful
$$4\coth^{-1}(e^\pi)$$
and [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=+4acoth%5C%2840%29Power%5Be%2Cpi%5D%5C%2841%29+-Sum%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2841%29%2Ck%5D%5C%2891%29k+log%5C%2840%29Divide%5BPower%5Bk%2C4%5D%2B2Power%5Bk%2C3%5D%2BPower%5Bk%2C2%5D%2CPower%5Bk%2C4%5D%2B2Power%5Bk%2C3%5D%2B3Power%5Bk%2C2%5D%2B2k%2B2%5D%5C%2841%29%2Blog%5C%2840%29Divide%5BPower%5Bk%2C2%5D%2B2k%2B1%2CPower%5Bk%2C2%5D%2B1%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2893%29%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C100%7D%5D) agrees.

By the way, I tried to prove it: the arguments of the $\ln$'s all factor, and with lots of simplifications the summand inside the brackets reduces to
$$[\ 2k\ln(k)+2(k+1)\ln(k+1)-(k+1)\ln(k^2+1)-k\ln(k^2+2k+2)\ ] $$
With this new representation and some struggle (it's not difficult, just some algebraic manipulations), I managed to equate the original sum to the sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\left[\ -2k \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{k+1}{k^2+k+1}\right)- (k+1)\ln\left(\frac{k^2+1}{(k+1)^2}\right) \right] $$
but from here, I couldn't proceed any further. At this point, I even think this made it only worse.

In addition, notice that
$$4\coth^{-1}(e^\pi)=2\ln\left(\frac{e^\pi+1}{e^\pi-1}\right)=2\ln\left(\coth\left(\frac\pi2\right) \right)$$

which follows just from the definition of inverse $\coth$, and maybe this is a bit easier to work with.

If anyone has any idea on how to attack this monster, or comes up with a full solution, please share, I look forward to read it.

Comment: To evaluate the partial sums, can use $\sum (-1)^n a_n=\sum a_{2n}-\sum a_{2n+1}$, exponentiate the summands and turn it into a product, and use [this partial product](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=prod%5B%28n%2Ba%29%5En%5D). Then, you would take $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ of it somehow.

Comment: Where does this series come from?

Comment: @Dan a friend presented it to me as a challenge in Uni knowing I love these sort of things

Comment: The series can be converted into the following integral:
$$2\coth^{-1}(e^\pi)-\int_0^\infty \frac{2\arctan(t)+2t\ln(t)+t\ln(1+t^2)-\frac12t\ln(4+t^4)}{\sinh(\pi t)}dt\\
+\int_0^1 \frac{t\ln(1-t^2)}{\sinh(\pi t)}dt+\int_1^\infty \frac{t\ln(t^2-1)}{\sinh(\pi t)}dt$$ where those integrals give $2\coth^{-1}(e^\pi)$, tested numerically.

Comment: They are alternating series, which are not convergent absolutely, hence you can't re-arrange them in this way. $$\lim_{k\to\infty} k\ln k+(k+1)\ln(k+1)\neq 0$$, the series is divergent. @Cliff

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we write the partial sum as:

$$S_{2N}=\sum_{k=1}^{2N}(-1)^k[\ 2k\ln(k)+2(k+1)\ln(k+1)-(k+1)\ln(k^2+1)-k\ln(k^2+2k+2)\ ] $$

and $S_{2N+1}$ can be treated similarly. Next, we group $S_{2N}$ into three parts:

$$S_{2N}=A+B+C $$

where

$$\begin{align}A&=\sum_{k=1}^{2N}(-1)^k[\ 2k\ln(k)+2(k+1)\ln(k+1)\ ]=2(2N+1)\ln(2N+1)\\
\\
B&=-\sum_{k=1}^{2N}(-1)^k[\ (k-1)\ln(k^2+1) +k\ln\left((k+1)^2+1\right)\ ]=-2N\ln\left((2N+1)^2+1\right)\\
\\
C&=-2\sum_{k=0}^{2N}(-1)^k\ln(k^2+1)\end{align}$$

For $C$, we use Abel-Plana formula for alternating sums ([derivations can be found in my old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4702171/abel-plana-formula-for-int-0-infty-fracfxe2-pi-x-1dx-and-int-0))

$$\begin{align}\boxed{\sum_{k=0}^{2N} (-1)^kf(k)=\frac{f(0)+f(2N)}{2}-\Im\int_0^\infty \frac{f(it)}{\sinh(\pi t)}dt\\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+\sum_{s=1}^m\frac{B_{2s}}{(2s)!}(4^s-1)f^{(2s-1)}(x)\bigg|_{x=2N}+\hat{R_3}}\tag{1}\end{align}$$

where $f(k)=\ln(k^2+1)$, we get

$$C=-\ln\left( (2N)^2+1\right)+2\int_1^\infty \frac{\pi}{\sinh(\pi t)}dt+\sum_{s=1}^m\frac{B_{2s}}{(2s)!}(4^s-1)f^{(2s-1)}(x)\bigg|_{x=2N}+\hat{R_3}$$

Now, we put $A, B, C$ together,

$$\begin{align}S_{2N}&=2(2N+1)\ln(2N+1)-2N\ln\left((2N+1)^2+1\right)-\ln\left( (2N)^2+1\right)\\
\\
&+2\int_1^\infty \frac{\pi}{\sinh(\pi t)}dt+\sum_{s=1}^m\frac{B_{2s}}{(2s)!}(4^s-1)f^{(2s-1)}(x)\bigg|_{x=2N}+\hat{R_3}\end{align}\tag{2}$$

Take the limit for eq.(2), and note that

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} 2(2N+1)\ln(2N+1)-2N\ln\left((2N+1)^2+1\right)-\ln\left( (2N)^2+1\right)=0$$

and

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \left[\sum_{s=1}^m\frac{B_{2s}}{(2s)!}(4^s-1)f^{(2s-1)}(x)\bigg|_{x=2N}+\hat{R_3}\right]=0\tag{3}$$

Therefore,

$$\boxed{~S=\lim_{N\to\infty}S_{2N}=2\int_1^\infty \frac{\pi}{\sinh(\pi t)}dt=4\coth^{-1}(e^\pi)~~}$$

---

**Remarks:**

For eq.(3), $m\ge1$ is some arbitrary interger, i.e, we set $m=1$

$$f'(2N)=\frac{4N}{1+4N^2}\longrightarrow 0$$

For the [tail part](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10), $\hat{R_3}=2\hat{R}(n=N)-\hat{R}(n=2N)$, and

$$\hat{R}(n)=-\Im\int_0^\infty f''(n+i\theta y)\frac{y^2}{e^{2\pi y}-1}dy$$

where $\theta\in (0,1)$, and plug in $f(x)=\ln(1+x^2)$

$$\Im f''(N+i\theta y)=\frac{2(\theta y-1)N}{(N^2+(\theta y-1)^2)^2}+\frac{2(\theta y+1)N}{(N^2+(\theta y+1)^2)^2}\le \frac{4\theta y}{N^3}$$

Since the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{y^3}{e^{2\pi y}-1}dy$ is convergent, hence,

$$\hat{R_3}\propto\hat{R}(N)\propto \frac1{N^3}\longrightarrow 0$$

Comment: Hi, can you add some details about how to evaluate the second limit? The one with $f^{(2s-1)}(x)\bigg|_{x=2N}$ and $\hat{R_3}$? I don't see a quick way to do it so I ask for your clarification, thank you

Comment: For $s=1$, you get $\displaystyle f'(x=2N)=\frac{4N}{1+4N^2}\to 0$, where $m$ is some arbitrary integer, for example, you can set $m=1$. More details can be found in my old post here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4702171/abel-plana-formula-for-int-0-infty-fracfxe2-pi-x-1dx-and-int-0

Comment: $\hat{R_3}\propto \frac1{N^3}\to 0$

Comment: @MathFail maybe some connection between both solutions that are we missing?

Comment: Can you be more specific on the idea? @User

Comment: Think that Abel-Plana formula can be applyed to obtain infinite products in cases in which $f(k)$ is a logarihtmic function. Also think Abel-Plana formula implies Stirling's formula.

Comment: @User The infinite product can be converted to infinite sum (or vice versa) by taking $\ln$, hence we can find the asymptotic expansion for $\ln (n!)$ (equivalently, $n!$) by using Abel-Plana formula and get the Stirling's formula. I did an integral in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4491717/use-abel-plana-formula-to-compute-int-0-infty-frac-arctante2-pi-t-1) which show the connection between this two formulas (see the second last line in the answer post).

Comment: (+1) @MathFail beautiful connection.

Answer (score 5):

Your sum can be rewritten as the following infinite product (exponential plus separation in even and odd terms):
$$S=\log{P} \\=\log{\left(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2n^2-2n+1}{2n^2+2n+1} \right)^{2n}\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n-1} \right)^{4n}\left(\frac{(2n+1)^2(2n-1)^2}{4n^2+1} \right) \right)}.$$
First we must note that:
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(2n+1)^2(2n-1)^2}{4n^2+1}\right) =\frac{1}{\sinh^2{(\frac{\pi}{2})}},\tag{1}$$
which is easy to obtain from the well known infinite products of $\sinh{(x)}$ and $\cosh{(x)}$ (check it).
In other hand we are going to consider:
$$P_{k}(a)=\prod_{n=1}^{k}\left( \frac{1}{e}\left(\frac{n+a}{n-1+a}\right)^{n} \right),$$
with arbitrary $a$. The partial product is equivalent:
$$P_{k}(a)=\frac{(k+a)^{k}}{e^{k}a(a+1)\cdot \cdot \cdot (k-1+a)}=\frac{(k+a)^{k+1}\Gamma{(a)}}{e^{k}\Gamma{(k+1+a)}}\sim\frac{e^{a}\Gamma{(a)}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(k+a)^{1/2-a} ,$$
Where we have used Stirling's formula in the last step. Putting $a=1/2$ in this last formula we get for first:
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e}\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}\right)^{n}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{e}{2}},\tag{2}$$
Extending this to the quadratic case $a=(1+it)/2$ with $t \in {\rm I\!R}$ then $\lim |P_{k}(a)|^{2}$ exists and
since:
$$|\Gamma(a)|^2=\frac{\pi}{\cosh{(\pi t/2)}},$$
we have:
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e^{2}}\left(\frac{4n^2+4n+t^2+1}{4n^2-4n+t^2+1}\right)^n \right)=\frac{e}{2\cosh({\pi t/2})}\tag{3}.$$
Now combining $(2)$ and $(3)$ we have:
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\left(\frac{4n^2-4n+t^2+1}{4n^2+4n+t^2+1} \right)^{2n}\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n-1} \right)^{4n}\right)=\cosh^2(\frac{\pi t}{2})\tag{4}.$$
Thus using $(1)$ and $(4)$ when $t=1$ gives:
$$P=\left(\frac{\cosh{(\pi/2)}}{\sinh{(\pi/2)}}\right)^2=\coth^2{(\pi/2)} \implies S=2\log{(\coth{(\pi/2)})}.$$
Let me know if you need more details to obtain $(1)$.

**Remarks:**
As suggested by @Zima.

1. When $a=\frac{1+it}{2}$:
   $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\left( \frac{1}{e}\left(\frac{n+a}{n-1+a}\right)^{n}\right)\right|^2=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e^{2}}\left(\frac{4n^2+4n+t^2+1}{4n^2-4n+t^2+1}\right)^n \right)=\frac{e}{2\cosh({\pi t/2})}.$$
2. We have proved: $$P_{1}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e}\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}\right)^{n}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{e}{2}},$$
   and
   $$P_{2}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e^{2}}\left(\frac{4n^2+4n+t^2+1}{4n^2-4n+t^2+1}\right)^n \right)=\frac{e}{2\cosh({\pi t/2})},$$
   which implies $$\frac{P_{1}^4}{P_{2}^2}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\left(\frac{4n^2-4n+t^2+1}{4n^2+4n+t^2+1} \right)^{2n}\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n-1} \right)^{4n}\right)=\cosh^2(\frac{\pi t}{2})$$

Comment: ok @Zima I will improve the answer with full details thanks.

Comment: @Zima I have made some changes. Best all.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer. I particularly like it beacuse it uses only "elementary" math, thank you @User

Comment: Nice problem @Zima

Comment: Hi @Zima thinking on this problem I arrived to: $$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left( \left(\frac{k^2}{k^2-1} \right)^{2(-1)^{k}} \left(\frac{k+1}{k-1} \right)^{k(-1)^{k}}\left(1+\frac{2}{k} \right)^{k(-1)^{k+1}} \right)=\frac{\pi^6}{384}.$$ Best all.

Comment: Neat result, your product can be further simplified to 
$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac  {\left(2k\right)^{4k+7}\left(2k+3\right)^{2k+1}}   {\left(2k-1\right)^{2k+2}\left(2k+1\right)^7\left(2k+2\right)^{4k-1}}=\frac{\pi^6}{384}$$ which I think is beatiful. @User

Answer (score 3):

I guess I'm very late for writing an answer now, but please allow me to provide a more elementary way to evaluate this sum.
First we have,
\begin{align*}
S=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( -1 \right) ^n\left[ n\ln \left( \frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{n^4+2n^3+3n^2+2n+2} \right) +\ln \left( \frac{n^2+2n+1}{n^2+1} \right) \right]}
\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( -1 \right) ^n\left[ n\ln \left( \frac{\left( n+1 \right) ^2n^2}{\left( \left( n+1 \right) ^2+1 \right) \left( n^2+1 \right)} \right) +\ln \left( \frac{\left( n+1 \right) ^2}{n^2+1} \right) \right]}
\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( -1 \right) ^n\left[ n\ln \left( \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} \right) +\left( n+1 \right) \ln \left( \frac{\left( n+1 \right) ^2}{\left( n+1 \right) ^2+1} \right) +\ln \left( \frac{\left( n+1 \right) ^2+1}{n^2+1} \right) \right]}
\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( -1 \right) ^n\left[ n\ln \left( \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} \right) +\left( n+1 \right) \ln \left( \frac{\left( n+1 \right) ^2}{\left( n+1 \right) ^2+1} \right) \right]}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( -1 \right) ^n\ln \left( \frac{\left( n+1 \right) ^2+1}{n^2+1} \right)}
\\
=&L_1+L_2
\end{align*}
$L_1$ is actually a telescoping sum, and is easy to evaluate
\begin{align*}
L_1=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( -1 \right) ^n\left[ n\ln \left( \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} \right) +\left( n+1 \right) \ln \left( \frac{\left( n+1 \right) ^2}{\left( n+1 \right) ^2+1} \right) \right]}
\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( \left( -1 \right) ^nn\ln \left( \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} \right) -\left( -1 \right) ^{n+1}\left( n+1 \right) \ln \left( \frac{\left( n+1 \right) ^2}{\left( n+1 \right) ^2+1} \right) \right)}
\\
=&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \left( \sum_{n=1}^N{\left( -1 \right) ^nn\ln \left( \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} \right)}-\sum_{n=1}^N{\left( -1 \right) ^{n+1}\left( n+1 \right) \ln \left( \frac{\left( n+1 \right) ^2}{\left( n+1 \right) ^2+1} \right)} \right) 
\\
=&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \left( \sum_{n=1}^N{\left( -1 \right) ^nn\ln \left( \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} \right)}-\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}{\left( -1 \right) ^nn\ln \left( \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} \right)} \right) 
\\
=&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \left( \ln \left( 2 \right) -\left( -1 \right) ^{N+1}\left( N+1 \right) \ln \left( \frac{\left( N+1 \right) ^2}{\left( N+1 \right) ^2+1} \right) \right) 
\\
=&\ln \left( 2 \right) 
\end{align*}
$L_2$ is more complicated, but it is not crazily hard.
\begin{align*}
L_2=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( -1 \right) ^n\ln \left( \frac{\left( n+1 \right) ^2+1}{n^2+1} \right)}
\\
=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left( -1 \right) ^n\ln \left( \frac{\left( n+1 \right) ^2+1}{n^2+1} \right)}-\ln \left( 2 \right) 
\\
=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left( \ln \left( \frac{\left( 2n+1 \right) ^2+1}{\left( 2n \right) ^2+1} \right) -\ln \left( \frac{\left( 2n+2 \right) ^2+1}{\left( 2n+1 \right) ^2+1} \right) \right)}-\ln \left( 2 \right) 
\\
=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\ln \left( \frac{\left( \left( 2n+1 \right) ^2+1 \right) ^2}{\left( 4n^2+1 \right) \left( 4\left( n+1 \right) ^2+1 \right)} \right)}-\ln \left( 2 \right) 
\\
=&\ln \left( \prod_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( \left( 2n+1 \right) ^2+1 \right) ^2}{\left( 4n^2+1 \right) \left( 4\left( n+1 \right) ^2+1 \right)}} \right) -\ln \left( 2 \right) 
\\
=&\ln \left( \coth ^2\left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \right) -\ln \left( 2 \right) 
\end{align*}
I should elabroate on the product. We got these well-known Weierstrass products of sine and cosine
$$
\begin{matrix}
 \frac{\sin \left( x \right)}{x}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( 1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi ^2} \right)}&  \cos \left( x \right) =\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left( 1-\frac{4x^2}{\left( 2n+1 \right) ^2\pi ^2} \right)}\\
\end{matrix}
$$
We can plug in different arguments (complex-valued ones too) into these expression and get
$$
\begin{matrix}
 \frac{2}{\pi}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{4n^2-1}{4n^2} \right)}&  \frac{2}{\pi}\sinh \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) =\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{4n^2+1}{4n^2} \right)}&  \cos \left( \pi \right) =\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left( 1-\frac{4}{\left( 2n+1 \right) ^2} \right)}&  \cosh \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) =\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{\left( 2n+1 \right) ^2+1}{\left( 2n+1 \right) ^2} \right)}\\
\end{matrix}
$$
So we have
$$
\begin{matrix}
 \sinh \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) =\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{4n^2+1}{4n^2-1} \right)},&  -\sinh \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) =\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{4n^2+1}{4n^2-1} \right)}\\
\end{matrix}
$$
From that we have
\begin{align*}
-\frac{\cosh \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \cosh \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right)}{\sinh \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \sinh \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right)}=&\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{4n^2-1}{4n^2+1} \right) \left( \frac{4\left( n+1 \right) ^2-1}{4\left( n+1 \right) ^2+1} \right) \frac{\left( \left( 2n+1 \right) ^2+1 \right) ^2}{\left( 2n+1 \right) ^4}}
\\
=&\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{\left( \left( 2n+1 \right) ^2+1 \right) ^2}{\left( 4n^2+1 \right) \left( 4\left( n+1 \right) ^2+1 \right)} \right) \left( \frac{\left( 2n+1 \right) ^2-4}{\left( 2n+1 \right) ^2} \right)}
\\
=&\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{\left( \left( 2n+1 \right) ^2+1 \right) ^2}{\left( 4n^2+1 \right) \left( 4\left( n+1 \right) ^2+1 \right)} \right)}\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left( 1-\frac{4}{\left( 2n+1 \right) ^2} \right)}
\\
=&\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{\left( \left( 2n+1 \right) ^2+1 \right) ^2}{\left( 4n^2+1 \right) \left( 4\left( n+1 \right) ^2+1 \right)} \right)}\,\,\cos \left( \pi \right) 
\end{align*}
$$
\Rightarrow \coth ^2\left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) =\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{\left( \left( 2n+1 \right) ^2+1 \right) ^2}{\left( 4n^2+1 \right) \left( 4\left( n+1 \right) ^2+1 \right)} \right)}
$$
So, at the end, the sum is equal to
$$
S=L_1+L_2=\ln \left( 2 \right) +\ln \left( \coth ^2\left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \right) -\ln \left( 2 \right) =2\ln \left( \coth \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \right) 
$$

Comment: (+1) Self contained. Also do yo know that Euler's product for $\sin{x}$ implies Stirling's formula?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this approach is fascinating, I am only concerned about the splitting of $S=L_1+L_2$. Shouldn't you be allowed to do that if and only if the two series are absolutely convergent? From a first look I think $L_2$ is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: @Zima the splitting is for aesthetic reasons, the more rigorous way is to convert the series into limit of a partial sum from the get-go, but that would be very messy to look at. Eventually, you would be left with the part with that product.

Comment: @User I don't know that fact, from what I know Weierstrass product is derived rigorously via complex analysis, and Sterling's formula, according to my analysis book, is derived from Wallis product... So that's what you meant?

Comment: Ok.  I will post the proof I know that Euler's product implies Stirling's formula. The classical proof follows from Wallis's product as you said. @Zima do you want to see that proof? Let me know. Best all.

Comment: @User yes please, I would like to see the proof. Feel free to share it in this post's answer section, clarifying that it is not an actual answer, thank you.

Comment: I've posted it @Zima . Best all.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer.**

This only wants to show a proof of Stirling's formula using Euler's infinite product for $\sin{x}$.
We have the following:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\log{\left( \frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{\pi x (1-x^2)} \right)}dx=3-\log{(8\pi)}\tag{1}.$$
This integral is elementary. The reader should have not problems to check it.
In other hand we have:
$$ \frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{\pi x (1-x^2)}=\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2} \right)\tag{2}.$$
The infinite product has uniform convergence from Weierstrass's theorem for infinite products.
So combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ and using uniform convergence we can confirm that:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\log{\left(\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2} \right)\right)}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\log{\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2} \right)}dx\\
=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\log{\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2} \right)}dx=3-\log{(8\pi)}.$$
Since:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\log{\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2} \right)}dx=\left((x-n)\log{(\frac{x-n}{n})}+(x+n)\log{(\frac{x+n}{n})} -2x \right) \Big|_{0}^{1},$$
we have:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left( (n-1)\log{(\frac{n}{n-1})}+(n+1)\log{(\frac{n+1}{n})} -2 \right)=3-\log{(8\pi)},$$
exponential in this last gives:
$$
\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{e^{2}}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1} \right)^{n} \right)=\frac{e^{3}}{8\pi}\tag{3}.
$$
Since the following product is telescopic:
$$\lim_{N}\prod_{n=2}^{N}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\lim_{N}\prod_{n=2}^{N}\left(\frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{n\cdot n}\right)=\lim_{N}\frac{N+1}{2N}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
using this last in $(3)$ we have:
$$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{e^{2}}\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1} \right)^{n} \right)=\frac{e^{3}}{4\pi}.\tag{4}$$
which is equivalent to Stirling's formula.

If we consider the partial product of $(4)$ as $N$ tends to infinity, we have:
$$\lim_{N}P_{N}=\lim_{N}\prod_{n=2}^{N}\left( \frac{1}{e^{2}}\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1} \right)^{n} \right)\\=e^{2-2N}2^{-3}3^{-2}4^{-2}\cdot \cdot \cdot (N+1)^{-2}N^{N-1}(N+1)^{N}\\=\lim_{N}\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{2-2N}N^{N+1}(N+1)^{N}}{N!^2}=\frac{e^{3}}{4\pi},$$
so:
$$\lim_{N}\frac{N^{N+1}(N+1)^{N}}{e^{2N}N!^2}=\frac{e}{2\pi},$$
taking the square root in this last:
$$\lim_{N}\frac{N^{N/2+1/2}(N+1)^{N/2}}{e^{N}N!}=\frac{\sqrt{e}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.$$
Finally since $\lim_{N}\left({\frac{1+N}{N}}\right)^{N}=e$, then:
$$\lim_{N}\frac{N^{N/2+1/2}(N+1)^{N/2}}{\left({\frac{1+N}{N}}\right)^{N/2}e^{N}N!}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\implies \lim_{N}\frac{e^{N}N!}{N^{N+1/2}}=\sqrt{2\pi}.$$
And we are done.

An elementary proof for the Euler's product was done by
Venkatachaliengar in 1962.

1. Venkatachaliengar. K: "Elementary proofs of the infinite product for $\sin{z}$ and allied formulae". American Mathematical Monthly, 69, 1962, 541-545.

Comment: nice solution!!

Comment: Thanks @oO_ƲRF_Oo but maybe is not the most elementary. Best all.